# Hosting a server behind NAT

Tags: php, sockets, server, ip-address, nat

So basically my PC is behind NAT.
I have total 3 IP addresses,
1. MY ISP Public Address. (27.106.96.113)
This address has been showed up when I google for "My IP".
2. MY Private Address that My ISP has given me. (172.16.91.141)
This address has been showed up in my router as my Public Address.
3. My actual Private Address. (192.168.0.100)
This IP Address is set for my PC by My Router(192.168.0.1) via DHCP.
I can access my PC locally with this(192.168.0.100) address.
I can access my PC inside My ISP network (People with same ISP as I have) with this(172.16.91.141) address.
However I cannot access my PC globally with this(27.106.96.113) address.
I know this is happening because my ISP having NAT Configuration so my Global IP is useless.
Now I am unable to host Apache(for php) neither Java Servlet Page nor my Counter-Strike 1.6 Game server Globally because of my ISP's NAT.
I tried to find solution for this but failed.
I have my free php host (let's say my.hosting.com) which is Globally accessible .
so I thought if I used Socket Programming in my PHP web host and make connection from my PC to PHP web host (Which is Globally accessible) then I have a tunnel through PHP web host and my PC.
And then I will redirect all internet traffic from my PHP web host to my PC.
so if i redirect all my internet traffic from (my.hosting.com:80) to (192.168.0.100:8080) then I can connect to my server by connecting to my PHP web host.
Now I am new to PHP and never tried socket programming.
This is just my thought and this may sound as foolish if I mistaking the concept of PHP Socket Programming.
Therefore I extremely need help from you guys in order to successfully connect my PC Globally.
Thank you so much for reading this and please help me to solve my problem.
Thank You.

Comment: Far too broad imo. I'd (usually) suggest actually trying what you're asking for and come ask a question when you hit a problem. But in this case, I don't think this is a viable solution, nor do I see the benefits over proper hosted servers.

Comment: when redirecting the traffic from your web host to your "localhost" the exactly same issue would appear. How about just setting properly your modem/router to forward the traffic to your localhost?

Comment: thank you for comment, actually I will transfer traffic to my router's IP address and then forward it to my PC using router configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So judging by what your trying to achieve, your best bet is to just ask your ISP to create a NAT on a spare TCP port (If they will let you) to NAT that specific traffic to your gateway 172.16.91.141, then you will need create a NAT rule on your router to NAT that traffic (say it was '8080' from your ISP router) and convert you could then convert it back to '80'.

WAN->ISP Router(27.106.96.113 - 8080 to 8080)->Your Router(172.16.91.141 8080 to 80)->Your Web Server(http://192.168.0.100:80)

Your IP address looks to be static as they've only got a block of 254 addresses so you shouldn't have to worry about it changing every so many days:

https://wq.apnic.net/whois-search/static/search.html?query=27.106.96.113

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I think calling my ISP is the only option left.

Comment: @Omkar Oh and don't forget you have a 'good leg to stand on' with your ISP as they are already double NAT'ing your connection to save money by using less external IP's.

Comment: Hey, just to let you know i tried "Hamachi" app for windows. It creates its own network and assigns one IP that can be reached among all users who installed "Hamachi" app in their PC. I am trying to know how it works. I thought "Hamachi" app uses some socket programming therefore I asked for PHP Socket Programming. But anyways I will try to figure out or just rent one VPS.

Comment: @Omkar Yeah I've used Hamachi before in the past but thought it was only one way VPN tunnel (non-routable back). Yeah it is possible to create some form of proxy using sockets but you would still need some form of relaying server to manage your connections. The most cost/time effective way to do this would be NAT (Double NAT in your case) or like you said a cheap VPS.

Comment: @Omkar dont forget to mark this question as answered if your happy. I've noticed that you have not marked any of your other questions as answered either so I would do this also.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. It took me 5 minutes to know how to mark an answer useful. But now all is good. actually I am new to this forum and I must say that you guys are doing great job helping other people. I have huge respect to all of helping people to this forum. Thank you again.

Comment: @Omkar No worries. The best way you can thank people is by marking answers if they are correct and up-voting and most of all, help others out if you can.

Answer (score 0):

*In before flame: This is actually no direct answer to the problem described above, but it could solve OPs problem.*

Have you ever heard about dynamic DNS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS. There are many dyndns providers (also for free) and a lot of internet routers natively support it by providing their public IP to the provider.

Instead of an IP you will get a domain name, like u0815.ddnsprovider.foo which you can use to access your PC through the routers port forwarding machanism.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried Dynamic DNS and no-ip.com but they redirect to my ISP's IP(27.106.96.113) which is not helping me to reach my PC.

Comment: @Omkar Yes this option will not work as your just adding an A record to your external IP address. This option would be needed if your external IP address was changing frequently (yours is not) and you PC/Server would just update the change of external IP to the Dynamic DNS service which in turn would update your A record.

Comment: Yep, there are also services like ngrok and remote.it, which are frequently used by authors of Jupyter Notebooks, creating AI cloud services in their mom's basement with python venv magic.